# Monotouch - Fast Forward/Rewind Audio Stream

Tags: xamarin.ios, audio-streaming, fast-forward

I'm using the Monotouch sample to play Audio file from a remote server (https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/StreamingAudio), and I need to implement the Fast forward and Rewind functionalities.

The StreamingPlayback Class has implements the OutputAudioQueue Play and Pause functions. I have worked with the AVAudioPlayer in Objective-C and could do something like:

```
-(void) rewind()   
{   
         myPlayer.currentTime -= 10.0;   
}
```

However with the OutputAudioQueue, the CurrentTime is Read-Only, and it looks to me like there is no way to implement the Rewind/Fast Forward with this. Anyone has a solution to this, or a better way to play my remote audio files?

Thanks

Comment: What type of file?  Does your server support range headers?